# Link image with session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have nave user on the header that should show the image of the user after he login but i dont know how i can show the user image depending on session called: UsrNme

```
<asp:Placeholder ID="loggedview" runat="server">
    <div class="loggedinview">
       <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Img") %>' CssClass="loggeduserimg" />
    </div>
</asp:Placeholder>
```

Comment: What is stored in Session["UsrNme"] - just user ID? How does this corresponds to the image - do you have images somewhere stored like "UserID.JPG" ?

Comment: There are several ways to put images, but you usually want to host your image somewhere, and use the link to that image on an img tag, eg. <img src="https://www.google.com.ni/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter in the user table in database there is a column which called Img it store the image of the user now when the user login to his account and the session save his UID "user name" the nave menu should show image depending on the session["UsrNme"] which is user name

Answer (score 1):

If your images are stored in a database a good approach would be to implement a custom HTTP handler (.ashx) which would serve your images as required.

MSDN documentation: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

There are tutorials available on how to create these if you do a search on Google. Your handler would just be responsible for loading the image from the database and writing it to the response.

You could then reference your images in your page as follows passing in a user identifier so the handler can load the correct image:

```
<img src="UserImage.ashx?userId=XXX" alt="User Image" />
```

Comment: i would like to ask you if that formula is ok to use session "UsrNme":  Text='<%# "/images/users/" + Eval("UsrNme") %>'

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're asking.